# Is there a way to see all the app updates/changes?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-games

I wonder if there is a way to see an android app updates/changes over the versions?

The changes that I want to see is those who the developer mentioned when he uploaded a new version to the Google store.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this site (just enter the app name):
http://www.apk4fun.com/